# 3D interpolation on python for integer depth layers

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, interpolation, mesh

I am new to python and interpolation. I have a DataFrame having 4 columns like this: (the actual df is big and is uploaded on my GitHub: https://github.com/SoniaBazargan/3D-interpolation/blob/main/MIT_absvalue.csv)

```
lat    lon   depth   velocity
5.27    -104.41   22.6.    5.6
5.27    -104.41   22.6.    5.7
.
.    
24.96    -80.51   67.8.    6.1
24.96    -80.51   67.8.    6.2
```

and I would like to find the velocity values at the same latitude and longitude but at different arbitrary depths.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata as gd
MIT = pd.read_csv('MIT_absvalue.csv', delim_whitespace=True, header = None)
MIT.columns = ['Lat', 'Long', 'Depth', 'Vabs']
x=MIT['Lat']
y=MIT['Long']
z=MIT['Depth']
v=MIT['Vabs']
xi,yi,zi=np.ogrid[5.27:24.96:29j, -104.41:-80.51:35j, 0:80:8j]
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(xi, yi, zi)
V = gd((x,y,z), v, (xx, yy, zz), method='linear')
```

The question is that: Using `np.ogrid`, I get depth layers that are not necessarily integer, and I need to get the V at arbitrary integer depth layers. How can I do that?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just replace `zi` in the line `xx,yy,zz=np.meshgrid(xi, yi, zi)` with an array of the integers that you're interested in? For starters e.g. `zi.round().astype('int')`.

Comment: Also are you sure you're happy with doing linear interpolation or is that just due to griddatas limitations? Seems questionable whether you get out something reasonable.

Comment: By now I think if you're only interested in interpolation and not extrapolation `method =linear` is fine. I could elaborate on why if you're interested.